# How can I speed up the aiohttp parser bs4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, aiohttp

The task is to get data from the site. I have 800 URLs to request. But it takes a long time .I use aiohttp. At this stage, I have received links, by clicking on each of them, I also get a number of links. I applied aiohttp, but the code is still slow: 390.9560036659241 sec. Sorry if this is a simple kind of question but I have little experience with asyncio so if anyone could help that would be massively appreciated. Thanks

```
import json
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import csv
import asyncio
import aiohttp

iso_data = []
iso_list = []
iso_catalogue = []
iso_links = ''
start_time = time.time()


async def get_page_data(session, url):          #get links 256 from main page
    url = "https://www.iso.org/standards-catalogue/browse-by-tc.html"

    async with session.get(url=url) as response:
        response_text = await response.text()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response_text, "lxml")
        iso_link = soup.find("tbody")

        for iso in iso_link.find_all("tr"):
            iso_url = iso.find('a').attrs['href']
            d = iso.find('a').text
            m = iso.find('td', {'data-title': 'Title'}).text

            try:
                level_2 = (f'{d}{m}').strip()
            except:
                level_2 = "nothing"
            iso_links = f'https://www.iso.org{iso_url}'
            iso_list.append(iso_links)
            iso_data.append({'level_1': 'tc', 'level_2': level_2})
        return iso_list


async def collect_data():                            #get 800 links
   
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for i in iso_list:
            response = await session.get(url=i)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "lxml")
            row = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'data-title': 'Subcommittee'})
            if row:
                for el in row:
                    a = el.find('a').attrs['href']
                    iso_catalogue.append(f'https://www.iso.org{a}')
            else:
                iso_catalogue.append(iso_links)
        return iso_catalogue


async def gather_data():
    url = "https://www.iso.org/standards-catalogue/browse-by-tc.html"
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get(url=url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "lxml")

        tasks = []

        task = asyncio.create_task(get_page_data(session, url))
        tasks.append(task)

        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

async def worker_iso(q):

    for urls in out:
        while True:
            response = await q.get(urls)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(await response.text(), "lxml")
            for i in soup.find_all('tr', {'ng-show': 'pChecked || pChecked == null'}):
                a1 = i.find('a').attrs['href']
                iso_standarts = f'https://www.iso.org{a1}'
                iso_standart.append(iso_standarts)

            q.task_done()


def main():

    asyncio.run(gather_data())
    asyncio.run(collect_data())

    cur_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M")

    finish_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Spend time: {finish_time}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
 ``
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I slightly reworked your example from the question. Now you're opening 256 links from main page in serial manner, so it takes time.

In my example I created 16 workers (coroutines) which share one Queue. The workers then wait for new values I put in the queue and process the request.

256 pages opened and processed on my computer in ~19 seconds:

```py
import tqdm  # <-- I use this for nice progress bar/timing
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

out = []


async def get_soup(session, url):
    async with session.get(url=url) as resp:
        return BeautifulSoup(await resp.text(), "lxml")


async def worker(session, q):
    while True:
        url, link_name, title = await q.get()

        soup = await get_soup(session, url)

        links = soup.select('[data-title="Subcommittee"] a')
        if links:
            for a in links:
                out.append("https://www.iso.org" + a["href"])
        else:
            out.append(url)

        q.task_done()


async def main():

    url = "https://www.iso.org/standards-catalogue/browse-by-tc.html"

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        soup = await get_soup(session, url)

        titles = soup.select('td[data-title="Title"]')
        links = soup.select('td[data-title="Committee"] a')

        committees = []
        for a, t in zip(links, titles):
            committees.append(
                [
                    "https://www.iso.org" + a["href"],
                    a.get_text(strip=True),
                    t.get_text(strip=True),
                ]
            )

        queue = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=16)

        tasks = []

        # create 16 workers that will process data in parallel
        for i in range(16):
            task = asyncio.create_task(worker(session, queue))
            tasks.append(task)

        # put some data to worker queue
        for c in tqdm.tqdm(committees):
            await queue.put(c)

        # wait for all data to be processed
        await queue.join()

        # cancel all worker tasks
        for task in tasks:
            task.cancel()

        # Wait until all worker tasks are cancelled.
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

        print(len(out))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Prints:

```
100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 256/256 [00:19<00:00, 13.18it/s]
653
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, it works really faster. Just one question, out of 653 links I need to add another 11,000 in total, how can I do this? I  should  create a other async function, and in main again split it into workers that will process data in parallel?

Comment: @Yuliia So from these 653 links you need to get another 11k links? Then wait until 653 links are scraped, then create another X workers like in the example and run them (probably creating some helper functions will clean the code)

Comment: Yes, I need to go through each 653 in turn and collect a list of urls around 11000, can you help with this? I added async def worker_iso(q) in post, collecting a list of urls, how now to split it into workers?

Comment: @Yuliia To not clutter the comments I'd suggest to open a new question here on StackOverflow. I'd try to look at it.

Comment: Yes, I am [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72248044/how-can-i-speed-up-parsing-with-aiohttp-workers-queue)